# Multiple inheritance in ontologies

Tags: owl, terminology, semantic-web, ontology, description-logic

I want to say that in my ontology each individual has exactly one most-specific type.

In this case:

1. Is it accurate to say my ontology does not allow multiple inheritance? I don't quite understand what multiple inheritance means in ontologies. Is this refer to `rdf:type` or `rdfs:subclassOf`? because I don't mind if a concept has multiple parents but I don't want individuals to have multiple types.
2. Is it accurate to say in my ontology all classes are pairwise disjoint, or should I say for instance in the ontology classes are pairwise disjoint unless they are participating in subsumption relation with each other?
3. Is there a better terminology or way to actually describe such ontologies?

Comment: This document uses the word "inheritance": https://www.w3.org/TR/sw-oosd-primer/

Comment: Can you restate the question without using the term "participates in". This doesn't have a defined meaning in OWL and I don't think you need it. You could say each individual has one most-specific type, all other types will be inferred via subClassOf axioms.

Comment: Thanks that make sense. I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

In literature you can find the expression "multiple inheritance" referring to both the extensional (`rdf:type`) and intensional (`rdfs:subclassOf`) meanings. RDF/OWL natively support both of them.

1. No, in general this is not correct. I don't think there is an official (and unambiguous) term for "individual being instance of multiple classes".
2. Your first statement is a sufficient condition, while the second one is necessary and sufficient. Alternatively, you can say that if two classes share an individual, then one of the two is a subclass of the other one.
3. I think that "one most-specific type" is already a well-describing terminology.

Answer (score 0):

In OWL, every individual `x` belong to a unique most specific class which is written `{x}` in conventional Description Logic syntax. In Turtle, you write it like this:

```
<x> a [
    owl:Class;
    owl:oneOf ( <x> )
] .
```

Any ontology thas has `x` as an individual entails the previous axiom. But maybe you mean "each individual belong to exactly one *named* class". In this case, consider the following case: assume there is a class `FlyingVehicle` with a subclass `Seaplane`, and a class `FloatingVehicle` with subclass `Seaplane`. If `x` has type `Seaplane`, then it has only one named type. However, there is multiple inheritance since it therefore belongs to the 2 named classes `FlyingVehicle` and  `FloatingVehicle` that are not related with a subclass relation.

You have to understand that an ontology (partially) describes a world or universe. Ontologies do not describe computational objects like OOP classes and methods do. You cannot prevent things to belong to multiple categories. Everything belong to multiple overlapping categories in the real world, and there are always "possible" universes where things belong to multiple categories, no matter how detailed or simple your descriptions are. However, you can restrict these by:

1. Providing design principles and guidelines in textual forms and enforce them by social means (e.g., make sure that in your project, nobody uses multiple `rdfs:subClassOf` and multiple `rdf:type`);
2. Enforce the restrictions and constraints computationally, by programming an application that checks what is allowed and disallowed;
3. Formalise these restrictions and constraints using various computer languages, but OWL ontologies are not the right tool for this.

I don't think there is a name for the kind of ontologies you are describing, but you may define a specification for a category of ontologies that ensure some desired effects and add additional instructions to how they should be used to enforce the desired effects. In Semantic Web standards, there is a formal language that can express some constraints that may be interesting to your application: [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/). It may not cover all that you need but may be a good place to start.